# Is there a JavaScript library for loading external scripts?

Tags: javascript

I know there is a lot of cross browser difficulties involved with loading external scripts asynchronously and providing callback functionality for when the script has been loaded. After quite a bit of research I've found several pretty sizeable JavaScript libraries that includes this functionality.

But what I'm searching for is a *small* library that is designed specifically for this task that I can embed into my application. The closest I've seen so far is [Bezen's load script loading module](http://bezen.org/javascript/src/bezen.load.js), but I don't know how reliable it is. My application must support all browsers with any market share to speak of, which unfortunately includes IE6.

I'm thinking there's probably a sleek tried & true JavaScript library out there that everybody uses but I can't find. Thanks for all suggestions, the best one will be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: What's wrong with [LABjs](http://labjs.com/)?

Comment: Any elaboration on that down vote? @raina77ow: LABjs looks nice, I'll check it out

Comment: Well, actually I thought LABjs was rejected by you as well, just wanted to know the reasons why. ) We started to use LABjs in our project to provide modularity, but right now are thinking about using RequireJS; it's sizy a bit, but it's well worth it for big projects with complex module dependencies. )

Comment: @raina77ow: require.js doesn't seem like it's designed for what I need. All I need is to be able to add jQuery to the page from Google CDN, then have a callback function run when the script has been loaded and run and jQuery is available. I don't need a full-fledged AMD library for that. LABjs looks more like it and I'll be sure to try it out. I still don't know what the down vote is all about though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [SidJS](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/sidjs-load-javascript-and-stylesheets-on-demand). All it does is, straight to the point, load a JS or CSS file by URL and provides callback functionality for when the file is loaded and ready.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps http://requirejs.org/ ?

**Edit**: according to your question comments, you to need this:

http://www.yterium.net/jQl-an-asynchronous-jQuery-Loader (700bytes minified and gziped)

> jQuery will be loaded without blocking browser rendering,
>   and during this all inline calls to `$(document).ready()`
>   will be queued.
>   As soon as jQuery is ready, all queued inline calls will be run
>   respecting their initial order

Perhaps the downvote was because you can find the answer to your question with a simple google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=async+jquery+load